# Knockout.js with jQuery templates, select box width goes to 0 width on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the problem built into a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XRdTD/

If you select something for the select box and then click `And`(it disappears, but it's still there) the select box shrinks down to a small size.  If I sent the select box to have a specific width, it only shows the first letter of the word.

This happens on IE9, which is the target browser.

What can I do to not make the select box shrink when I click `And`?

Comment: this looks like incorrect behavior of jquery templates + knockout + select binding in IE9. workaroung is to use {{each}} for filling select values - http://jsfiddle.net/XRdTD/2/  In case they won't be changed over time (in vm), I would even suggest hardcoding them in template http://jsfiddle.net/XRdTD/3/

Comment: Wow, thank you!  Both of those work wonderfully!  If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone will find it useful - when using knockout + jquery templates + options binding + value binding - select is somehow corrupted in IE9.

Workaround is to bind select options with jquery templates, and select value - with knockout http://jsfiddle.net/XRdTD/2/ or use hardcoded select values if possible - http://jsfiddle.net/XRdTD/3/